# Jekyll serve not generating .well-known folder and subfolders in assets

Tags: matrix, jekyll

I am setting up matrix and I need to have a .well-known folder which has a matrix subfolder which containers the client and server files. However, when I generate via `jekyll serve` it does not generate the .well-known folder.

I have tried using the include feature in _config.yml for a .well-known folder in the root directory of jekyll.

```
include:
  - .well-known
```

However, when I run `jekyll serve` it generates the .well-known folder and everything in it but when I go to that file it downloads it instead of displaying it.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thanks, Ash.